# is there a way to obtain ip of linked container using link alias?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers one link to another. As the following...

```
docker run -i -t --name container1 ubuntu:trusty

docker run -i -t --name container2 --link container1:aliasc1 ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
```

is there a simple way to obtain ip of `container1` from `container2` using link alias `aliasc1`?

I orchestrate container using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker will create an entry in `/etc/host` for the containers linked. So you can get that ip from there. I.e.:

`cat /etc/hosts | grep aliasc1 | awk {'print $1'}`

Comment: shorter `awk '/aliasc1/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

Docker automatically creates environment variables for this purpose. For example if `container1` exposes port 80, then `container2` will have `$ALIASC1_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR` defined.

See http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

You may try `getent`.

```
getent hosts aliasc1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/how-can-i-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-a-bash-script